# Loading python support in gdb

Tags: python, linux, gdb, archlinux

I've got a problem with getting python-specific commands working in gdb. I've got the general python support included:

```
(gdb) python print(True)
True
```

I've got the standard scripts installed:

```
$ ls /usr/share/gdb/python/gdb/
command  FrameDecorator.py  FrameIterator.py  frames.py  function  __init__.py  printer  printing.py  prompt.py  __pycache__  types.py  unwinder.py  xmethod.py
```

I made sure the loading is enabled with all paths I could:

```
$ cat ~/.gdbinit 
add-auto-load-safe-path /usr/share/gdb/python/gdb/
add-auto-load-safe-path /usr/share/gdb/python/
add-auto-load-safe-path /usr/share/gdb/
set auto-load python-scripts on
```

But for some reason gdb still doesn't like this:

```
(gdb) info auto-load 
gdb-scripts:  No auto-load scripts.
guile-scripts:  No auto-load scripts.
libthread-db:  No auto-loaded libthread-db.
local-gdbinit:  Local .gdbinit file was not found.
python-scripts:  No auto-load scripts.
```

I'd like to get the `py-bt` command working after loading `gdb`.

Comment: `info auto-load` only shows you if an auto-load script has in fact been loaded, not whether one is available to load.  You have to make sure that gdb has already seen the object with which the auto-load script is associated; for example if you `gdb python` and then `start`, to ensure that libpython.so is loaded into the inferior.

Comment: One thing to try is to find the file where `py-bt` is defined, and then make sure the containing directory is in some auto-load or debug-file directory that gdb will search. In general, the name of such a file would be `python*-gdb.py` or `libpython*-gdb.py` and would be somewhere in the tree of files under `/usr/lib/debug` or `/usr/share/gdb`.

Comment: I have the same problem. The official documentation says you have to add the path of `python-gdb.py` as `add-auto-load-safe-path` in `~\.gdbinit`, but gdb says to me too that no scripts are loaded. This is on CentOS 6.5 and gdb 7.2. On the contrary, it works on Ubuntu 14.04, gdb 7.7.1. Offical python documentation: https://docs.python.org/devguide/gdb.html

Comment: I encountered the same problem. The workaround working for me: paste this line source /home/likern/Projects/CPython/python3.6-3.6.3/python-gdb.py into ~/.gdbinit file.

Answer (score 7):

The `py-bt` and related commands are usually defined in a GDB script file `python*-gdb.py`, which tends to be present in `/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/bin/`. If those commands are not available for you in GDB when debugging a Python object file, it means that the script which contains them was not auto-loaded.

To find out why, enable `auto-load` debugging:

```
(gdb) set debug auto-load
```

and try to load Python executable:

```
(gdb) file python3
```

You should see output similar to this:

```
Reading symbols from python3...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/58/bce0c98a07039868053ed4b27e79959caadb9d.debug...done.
auto-load: Attempted file "/usr/lib/debug/.build-id/58/bce0c98a07039868053ed4b27e79959caadb9d.debug-gdb.gdb" does not exist.
auto-load: Expanded $-variables to "/usr/lib/debug:/usr/share/gdb/auto-load".
auto-load: Searching 'set auto-load scripts-directory' path "$debugdir:$datadir/auto-load".
auto-load: Attempted file "/usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/debug/.build-id/58/bce0c98a07039868053ed4b27e79959caadb9d.debug-gdb.gdb" does not exist.
auto-load: Attempted file "/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib/debug/.build-id/58/bce0c98a07039868053ed4b27e79959caadb9d.debug-gdb.gdb" does not exist.
auto-load: Attempted file "/usr/lib/debug/.build-id/58/bce0c98a07039868053ed4b27e79959caadb9d.debug-gdb.py" does not exist.
auto-load: Expanded $-variables to "/usr/lib/debug:/usr/share/gdb/auto-load".
auto-load: Searching 'set auto-load scripts-directory' path "$debugdir:$datadir/auto-load".
auto-load: Attempted file "/usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/debug/.build-id/58/bce0c98a07039868053ed4b27e79959caadb9d.debug-gdb.py" does not exist.
auto-load: Attempted file "/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib/debug/.build-id/58/bce0c98a07039868053ed4b27e79959caadb9d.debug-gdb.py" does not exist.
done.
auto-load: Attempted file "/usr/bin/python3.6-gdb.gdb" does not exist.
auto-load: Expanded $-variables to "/usr/lib/debug:/usr/share/gdb/auto-load".
auto-load: Searching 'set auto-load scripts-directory' path "$debugdir:$datadir/auto-load".
auto-load: Attempted file "/usr/lib/debug/usr/bin/python3.6-gdb.gdb" does not exist.
auto-load: Attempted file "/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/bin/python3.6-gdb.gdb" does not exist.
auto-load: Attempted file "/usr/bin/python3.6-gdb.py" does not exist.
auto-load: Expanded $-variables to "/usr/lib/debug:/usr/share/gdb/auto-load".
auto-load: Searching 'set auto-load scripts-directory' path "$debugdir:$datadir/auto-load".
auto-load: Attempted file "/usr/lib/debug/usr/bin/python3.6-gdb.py" does not exist.
auto-load: Attempted file "/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/bin/python3.6-gdb.py" exists.
auto-load: Loading python script "/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/bin/python3.6-gdb.py" by extension for objfile "/usr/bin/python3.6".
auto-load: Matching file "/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/bin/python3.6-gdb.py" to pattern "/usr/lib/debug"
auto-load: Not matched - pattern "/usr/lib/debug".
auto-load: Matching file "/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/bin/python3.6-gdb.py" to pattern "/usr/share/gdb/auto-load"
auto-load: Matched - file "/usr/share/gdb/auto-load" to pattern "/usr/share/gdb/auto-load".
auto-load: File "/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/bin/python3.6-gdb.py" matches directory "/usr/share/gdb/auto-load".
```

The rules which GDB uses to find the script to `auto-load` are described here:

https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Auto_002dloading-extensions.html

In a simplified form, it takes the absolute filepath of the loaded object file after following the symlinks, appends a `-gdb.(gdb|py|scm)` extension to it and tries to find a file whose path begins with one of the `auto-load` `scripts-directory` directories and ends with the constructed script name.

If no such scripts could be found, check which ones are actually available on your system. It might be possible that you are trying to debug e.g. a `python3` executable, which is a symlink to `python3.6`, while your system's GDB installation may only supply GDB scripts for `python3.5` executable. Because of the way the script names are constructed, the name of the executable actually *does* matter.

Also, check whether GDB is using the appropriate script directories:

```
(gdb) show auto-load scripts-directory
List of directories from which to load auto-loaded scripts is $debugdir:$datadir/auto-load.
```

and update them if necessary. When loading an object file with `auto-load` debugging enabled, the following line:

```
auto-load: Expanded $-variables to "/usr/lib/debug:/usr/share/gdb/auto-load".
```

shows the expanded value of the `scripts-directory`.

Finally, check the value of `auto-load` safe path:

```
(gdb) show auto-load safe-path
List of directories from which it is safe to auto-load files is $debugdir:$datadir/auto-load.
```

and also update it if necessary.

BTW, chances are you do not need any extra `add-auto-load-scripts-directory` or `add-auto-load-safe-path` commands in your `~/.gdbinit` file, because the default `auto-load` script directories and safe paths usually include `$datadir/auto-load`, which typically expands to `/usr/share/gdb/auto-load`, which is often the default location for system-wide GDB scripts where the `usr/bin/python*-gdb.py` files can most probably be found.

Comment: It's weird mine locates /usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib while it actually searches /..../auto-laod/usr/bin, and from there libstdcxx is not auto-loaded thus pretty-printer for STL does not work automatically

Comment: I am not sure what your issue is but it seems to be caused by some confusion between the `bin` and `lib` paths. Create a question and someone might be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

If auto loading fails, load the relevant script explicitly with the source command. For example:

```
sudo gdb python
source /usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/bin/python3.9-dbg-gdb.py
attach 123
pt-bt
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem on Debian 11. using

```
(gdb) set debug auto-load
(gdb) file python3
```

I found that gdb was trying to locate python3.9**d**-gdb.py in /usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/bin, but the filename actyally is python3.9**m**-gdb.py. The fix was to add another link:

```bash
cd /usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/bin
sudo ln -s python3.9m-gdb.py python3.9d-gdb.py
```